# Authenticating to Facebook Without Using any Browser Features

Tags: facebook, oauth

I apologize for the question. But I can not deal with the authentication on the Facebook as application. My application get access token with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

That's alright, I've got an access token. But how can I get user information then. I mean that user did not enter the username and password. Then how my application can access user information or post something on the wall?

Can anybody explain me the authentication algorithm to Facebook. But I need to do it without any browser's features. I mean that Facebook Dialogs is not for me. Then how?

Answer (score 0):

As of official docs you should still use emebed browser in your app. "Windows, OS X and Linux native apps" section here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

After you get access token you can get user info via api

- https://graph.facebook.com/me -- current user, need access token
- https://graph.facebook.com/{USER ID OR NICK}, example from docs: https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor

More api info is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Well, as I understood, there is no possibility to auth to Facebook without browser's features. It's sadly. My idea has been broken.